# How can I install package service to alpine Linux?

Tags: linux

I need to somehow install the service package on alpine linux, in order for my tests to run correctly. Tests are written using the testinfra module.
My test works fine on ubuntu and centos but doesn't work on alpine.

```
import testinfra

def test_nginx_running_and_enabled(host):
    nginx = host.service('nginx')
    assert nginx.is_running
    assert nginx.is_enabled
```

I get an error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
apk add --no-cache openrc
rc-service nginx status
```

Comment: not exactly what I meant, nginx is already installed there, the problem is that it is not checked, since there is no service command/utility on alpine linux

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. Answer updated (`openrc`)